# What design pattern can be applied to angular component where form changes are debounced to avoid losing change events

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am experiencing a frustrating issue with an Angular 14 application that I can only assume is caused by some fundamental design flaw to cause complications.

Imagine the app allows the user to navigate between questions in a questionnaire and each page has a form that allows the user to input data against it. The input fields of type text are debounced using the following code: -

```
        this._formGroupChangedSubscription = this.formGroup.valueChanges
            .pipe(debounceTime(400), distinctUntilChanged())
            .subscribe(() => {
                this.onValueChanges();
            });
```

This works fine until you try to be devilish with your input and enter some text into the input box and then very quickly click next to move to the next question. The data capture component is different depending on the question type thus the first component is destroyed and the subscription subsequently destroyed before it gets an opportunity to be executed.

Comment: call `this.onValueChanges();` prior to moving on to next question. If you don't have a hook for this event you'll have to create one

Comment: why just not create a boolean where you track whether or not your debounce has been hit. If not then the next step isn't available yet. Conversely, you can also probably store their data in a store and, when going back to the previous page, just recreate the form based on what they saved

Answer (score 0):

If the component destruction is the issue, move your subscription to a service or emit `this.formGroup` immediately onDestroy hook.

```js
ngOnDestory(): void {
   this.onValueChanges();
}
```

Comment: Yes that works if the question is of a different type however, if the next question is the same type then the component isn't destroyed.

Comment: Okay, I can see that happening via service. Then what about using the `onDestory` hook to emit the "question" right away? Then regardless if its the same type/same answer it will always be emitted before user leaves component. If you want some help on this I would need more relevant code. Right now I can't see what your component is doing actually.